# $ C_0(\mathbb{R}^2)$, $C(\mathbb{D})$, $C(\mathbb{T})$ and the index map

Tags: k-theory

Consider the short exact sequence

$$0 \longrightarrow C_0(\mathbb{R}^2) \overset{\varphi}\longrightarrow C(\mathbb{D}) \overset{\psi}\longrightarrow C(\mathbb{T}) \longrightarrow 0$$

I need to show that

1) $K_1(C(\mathbb{D}))=0$

2) $K_0(C(\mathbb{D}))\cong \mathbb{Z}$

3)  $K_o(\psi)$ is injective

And finally I need to conclude that $\delta_1: K_1(C(\mathbb{T})) \to K_0(C_0(\mathbb{R}^2))$ is an isomorphism and that $K_0(C_0(\mathbb{R}^2))$ is non zero.

Here $\mathbb{D}= \lbrace z \in \mathbb{C}: \vert z \vert \leq 1 \rbrace$ and  $\mathbb{T}= \lbrace z \in \mathbb{C}: \vert z \vert = 1 \rbrace$

I have already proved 1) and 2) but I am having some trouble with 3). I am using the book "Introduction to k-theory" by M. Rørdam.

By proposition 9.3.3 (Rørdam) the short exact sequence induce an exact sequence:

[image]

And by exactness we obtain that Im($K_0(\varphi)$)=Ker($K_0(\psi))$ so I want to show that that Im($K_0(\varphi)$)=Ker($K_0(\psi))=\lbrace 0 \rbrace$ as it the injectivity then follows. But I can't seem to prove this, so I was wondering if there is another way.

I can see how 1, 2 and 3 allows me to conclude that $\delta_1: K_1(C(\mathbb{T})) \to K_0(C_0(\mathbb{R}^2))$ is an isomorphism by using exactness, but how do I know that $K_0(C_0(\mathbb{R}^2))$ is non zero?

Comment: What kind of $k$-theory is this?

Comment: For $C^*$-algebras

Comment: In $1)$ / $K_1(C(\mathbb{D}))=0$, can you please show me how to prove that $K_1(C(\mathbb{D}))$ is trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $K_0(C\mathbb(\mathbb D))\cong\mathbb Z$, with generator the identity element $1\in C(\mathbb D)$.  Thus to show that $K_0(\psi)$ is injective, it is enough to show that $K_0(\varphi)[1]_0\neq0$.  But $\varphi$ takes the identity of $C(\mathbb D)$ to the identity of $C(\mathbb T)$, so $K_0(\varphi)[1]_0=[1]_0\neq 0$.

Upon knowing that $\delta_1$ is an isomorphism, we can conclude that $K_0(C_0(\mathbb R^2))$ is nonzero by showing that $K_1(C(\mathbb T))$ is nonzero, and the computation of $K_1(C(\mathbb T))$ is handled in [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3702621/show-that-k-n-mathbbta-is-isomorphic-to-k-na-oplus-k-n1-a-for-ev)

Comment: This is because $\mathbb D$ is contractible, and thus it has the same $K$-theory as a point.